# How can I find out what what branch is being pushed to during a Git hook?

Tags: git, github, githooks

I am setting up some git hooks being written in `bash`, and I want to know what branch is about to be pushed to using a `pre-push` hook.

Upon using the command `git push origin <branch>` or `git push`,
The pseudo logic would go something like this:

```
if [ remote branch about to be pushed to = master ] then;
  // do something
fi
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pre-push+hook

Comment: In the linked dup `local_ref` inside the loop is your local branch. See the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push

Comment: `$remote_ref`  variable in your your script, for the remote branch. `$local_ref` for the local branch name.

Comment: @Rakmo - I have tried echoing that variable, ```echo "$remote_ref"```, but it doesn't return anything, also - where is the variable coming from? I don't quite understand how this bit works. Thank you for your information

Answer (score -3):

If you are trying to find the current branch name you can use this

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Comment: Hi @sachin, I am trying to find the name of the branch being to pushed to, ie: the <remote>  branch, not the local branch